# select top 10 from a subset with Select Distinct statement

Tags: select, unique, distinct, group

I search and couldn't find any solution close to what I need.

I have this statement which list unique numbers from a table with dates. The following statement helped me with this and gave me a long list.

select distinct tfnumb,max(tfdate) over (partition by tfnumb) from turfbase as max_date

However, I wish to list only the top 10 or 20 with latest date. I don't know how to do that.
I tried the "Select Top" but it doesn't work. Help.

Appreciate any help. Thanks.
Regards
Daniel

I wish to list only the first top 10 or 20 rows from a table derived with the distinct statement.